# Error Building MonoDevelop Project - Your .NET Runtime does not support '-win32icon'

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm getting the following build error when trying to build a sample project using MonoDevelop:

```
Error CS8088: Your .NET Runtime does not support `-win32icon'. Please use the latest Mono runtime instead. (CS8088)
```

The only thing I've done is create a new, empty project and added some PNG files as the App Icons and Spotlight & Settings Icons. I know that the error is related to these icons in some way, but I can't find any reference to this particular issue. The PNG files were created from an EPS file using GIMP.

My system information is as follows:

- MonoDevelop 3.0.3.2
- NET Runtime => Mono 2.10.9 (Default)
- uname -a => Darwin unknown406c8f2c1099 11.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.0: Mon Apr  9 19:32:15 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.26.8~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you set a Win32 exe icon in your project options. It looks like the MonoTouch C# compiler has been modified to such icons, since they would be completely redundant on iOS. It should really be removed from the project options UI too, so it doesn't get set accidentally.

To fix the error, clear the "Win32 icon" field from the Build->General section in the Project Options.

Comment: That was it! I guess I got a little "icon happy" when playing around with the settings.